# grub - error: no such device on all disks/partitions

Tags: grub, solaris

In an environment with `Solaris 11.4` the S.O is not able to boot. I've research this problem other blogs and all them say to set the `root` and `prefix` for a appropriate partition after check the correct disk using the `ls`, the problem is that all disks and partitions has "unknown filesystem", the only exception is one partition used for oracle database:

[image]

[image]

the `set` output:

[image]

Some suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Your `prefix` contains an `@`, which is a mandatory part if your GRUB directory is on a ZFS filesystem, as it indicates the ZFS volume name. So try `ls (hd0)//@/` and all your other `ls` commands with the `//@/` suffix.

Comment: If that does not help, boot from an external media and verify the state of the ZFS volumes and the disk health status before doing anything else.

Comment: I've imported the rpool through an external media and the state is ok. I've followed this doc (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E60978/gkvdr.html) to try install the bootloader again, but still not working. I'm still looking for other solution